# jdbcDrive class could not be found

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb, classnotfound

I included the hsqldb.jar into the build path. Now I want to create a connection, but I've only get an error that the jdbcDriver could not be found. Here is my code:

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Dies Klasse liefert eine  JDBC Connection zurück
 * @author Christian
 *
 */
public class JDBCConnector {

    private Connection connection;

    public JDBCConnector(String url, String user, String password){
        try{
          Class.forName( "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" );
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ){
            System.err.println("Der Datenbanktreiber konnte nicht geladen werden");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Beim Erstellen der Verbindung ist ein Feheler aufgetreten.\n"
                    + "Bitte überprüfen Sie die URL, sowie Usernamen und Passwort");
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        if(connection != null){
            return connection;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Connection == null");
        }
    }


}
```

And her you see the libraray:
[image: Included Libraries]
And the stacktrace:

```
    Der Datenbanktreiber konnte nicht geladen werden
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.JDBCConnector.<init>(JDBCConnector.java:18)
    at org.apache.jsp.server.jsp.Access_jsp._jspService(Access_jsp.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 23, 2016 4:47:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Gefaehrdungsbeurteilung] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:200)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.server.jsp.Access_jsp._jspService(Access_jsp.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT:
Maybe it's improtant to know, that I created a SAPUI5 projekt, but I think it's not important to know

Answer (score 1):

Wrong class name.  I think it should be `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDriver.html

You should open the JAR and verify that the .class file does indeed exist and has the correct path structure.

Then you should verify that you understand CLASSPATH and included that JAR at both compile and run time.

Comment: I've changed the class name to org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver and it doesn't work either... I'm  not new to java, this is the first time this error occured, but it's also the first time I'm using eclipse

Comment: Too many things that you're ignorant of: Java, Eclipse, JDBC. No error messages means I can't tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The driver class is org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
and Connect URL:jdbc:hsqldb:databasename

Comment: Both driver classnames are valid.

All it does is extend org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver and is therefore just an alias to it.